# Is there a way to find the registered handlers in a svelte component?

Tags: svelte

In svelte, is there any way to check if a handler was declared on a component instance?

For instance, say you have a form, but you only want to show the delete button if a delete event handler is actually declared.

Consider the following:

```
/* App.svelte */
<MyForm
    on:save={handleSave}
    on:delete={handleDelete}
/>

/* MyForm.svelte */
<form on:submit={() => { dispatch('save'); }}>
    <!-- some inputs -->
    
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
    
    {#if hasDeleteEventHandler}
        <button 
            type="button"
            on:click={() => { dispatch('delete'); }}
        >
            Delete
        </button>
     {/if}
</form>
```

In the case above, I'd expect `hasDeleteEventHandler` to evaluate to `true` (and thus the delete button is rendered) since the `App` component declared a delete handler for its instance if `MyForm`.

Is there a way to figure out `hasDeleteEventHandler`?

Comment: you could try using add.eventlistener method to add event dyanamically and then checking if it's set or not in the lifecycle hook method

Comment: Why not just use callBack props like `onSave` or `onDelete` that can be `undefined` ?